# SpriteAnimation in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hey m plan to make particle effect by using Sprite animation ..but didnot get it in proper way ..
Is there any one who has work on it ??

And also suggest me how I move image respect to time ?...

Waiting for positive response ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to check out http://www.ezsprite.com , it's a nice spritesheet package for unity it works it's similar to the the animation system in flixel or cocos2d .. it can be used to create a particle effect manually .. I'm not 100% on if you could get it to work with the particle emitters in unity .. if you want to do that your best bet is to probably define a material with a shader that adjusts the uvs as time passes and use that with the emitter

Comment: the link u given is not exist